# legal iPhone / iPad distribution for ordered app

Tags: iphone, ipad, distribution

I'm kind a confused with Apple licenses and my way of thinking.

What is the legal way, that INDIE developer with 99$ license sells / creates custom app for third party (company or person) ?

For example, small coffee bar would like to use iPhone app for their waitress to enter orders which would then be sent to private server...

So, it is one time developed app, that would be installed to 3 devices.

According to Apple, that should end up on the store, because selling apps using ad-hoc distribution is illegal, ad-hoc distro is used for testing purposes only ?

App would cost 50$ so buying Enterprise licence to create 50$ app is nonsense, and I do not see legal way to earn 50$ ?

Can anyone help and explain me what and how to do it LEGALLY :)

p.s. I'm not in USA and B2B Volume distro is not an option.

Comment: this is a question that can only be answered by Apple themselves.  I suggest you contact them.

Answer (score 2):

We have had similar requirements with a number of clients. The simplest solution is to implement a user system. Since you are using a private server it should not be a problem. Create a login for each waitress and have the app request the user credentials at least once.

You will also obviously have to supply the Apple Review team with a test account but its perfectly fine to have a "private" app on the store.

Comment: so basically the app can be on the app store but can only be used by people with logins if I understand correctly?

Comment: @Armand that is correct. You will obviously have to supply the Apple Review team with a test account but its perfectly fine to have a "private" app on the store

Comment: reason for the +1, I would suggest updating your answer with it for completeness